# Complex Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel

Is this even possible? Here's what I'm trying to do:

This is a gigantic spread sheet with lots of data on lots of different things, one particular section of it is set up like so:

```
name1   name2   num1    num2
john    smith   3   
jane    doe     5   
samuel  jackson 0   
jackie  chan    2       12
abe     lincoln 19
```

Most of the time num2 is going to be left blank, but if there is an entry, I want to concatenate name1 and name2, with the space, and then apply the conditional formatting to cells in the spreadsheet that contain the concatenated name.

So in the above example, ANY cells in the spreadsheet containing "jackie chan" will be the target cells for the conditional formatting.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: If you add a helper column that contains the concatenated name it should be quite simple to base the CF on a COUNTIF function using that column. If there's no helper column, you can still base it on whether there's number in num2, and do the concatenation as well in the CF formula. I think. I'd start with the first idea and then see if I can do the 2nd based on it.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly copied to excel your data and tried to solve the problem.

In a column next to the data (`E`) I concatenated the two names if the num2 was not blank with the expression: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D2));A2&" "&B2;"")` otherwise I left it empty.

Created a little test column, where I've put some names apearing in the `E` column and some which not. Then I used the `=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()));$E$2:$E$6;1;0)))` expression to conditionally format the cells in the test column. In which `INDIRECT(...)` gets the cell's value, and if `VLOOKUP` does not find a match in the `E` column, it raises an `N/A` error, which is caught by the `ISERROR` function (not `ISERR`!).

Comment: fantastic, works like a charm (and I learned some new formulas)